# Search Issue in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, search, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new here and I have a question about a search piece of code in MVC 4. I have this piece of code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null)
{
    var model = entities.Users
                        .Where( m => searchTerm == null || m.SureName.Contains(searchTerm))
                        .Select(m => new UserViewModel
                            {
                                Name = m.Name,
                                SureName = m.SureName,
                                Department = m.Department,
                                Mail = m.Mail
                            });
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm " />
    <input type="submit" value="Search ..." />
</form>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        <h4>@item.Name, @item.SureName</h4>
        <div>@item.Department, @item.Mail</div>
    </div> 
}
```

When I run this it is working till I want to search anything. Problem is in routing. Because if I will manually type ":XXXX/?searchTerm=Luk" everything is working fine. But when I do the same on the page URL looks like this ":XXXX/?searchTerm+=Luk". Does anybody know, why there is that + mark ?? I think that is the issue I have here.

Comment: `+` is used for spaces () in url

Comment: The + comes from the whitespace between the m and the end quote in name="searchTerm "

Comment: Give your question a **meaningful** title please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a whitespace here:

```
<input type="search" name="searchTerm " />
```

This will be HTML encoded to a "+" in your query string. Remove the whitespace from the "name" attribute and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much ... I was look over that little thing .. ,o)